# Opening DispForm.aspx for a specific list item using URL

Tags: 2013, hyperlink, display-form

I'd like to enter a SharePoint list item in detail using a Hyperlink. I've already figuered out, that it works with something like

```
http://SharePointUrl/Site/List/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

But in my Scenario i'd like to enter the detailed view of the list element with only knowing it's title. For using the title column as a "Primary key" I've set it unique. When applying the column title to the Hyperlink it looks like

```
http://SharePointUrl/Site/List/DispForm.aspx?title='ABC001'
```

But then I just get the empty Display Form. Does anyone know how to solve this or has a different approach for that?

Thanks!
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation marks, your URL string should then read:

```
http://SharePointUrl/Site/List/DispForm.aspx?title=ABC001
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Already tried this one, without quotation marks I also get an empty mask.

Comment: Is your url in the format http://SharePointUrl/site/lists/listname/DispForm.aspx?title=ABC001   ?? EDIT: the only reason it would be returning an empty mask, is an incorrect is that the value aren't matched exactly, I can only suggest checking the values match like-for-like :/

Comment: Yeah it is in that url format and I've checked it several times :/ I've already considered that its maybe not allowed by SharePoint to use a different key for accessing the Display Form. But that would be ****

Comment: Testing it myself, I created two items with the same title to see if it would cause a conflict, it doesn't, but will bring back the item with the lesser ID value always. Here's the url I've been using: `http://mysharepointsite.local/sites/testsite/Lists/Test%20List/dispForm.aspx?title=TEST 10`

Comment: Well tried it with another SharePoint Site and its the same result... still an empty mask, which SharePoint version your running?

Comment: SharePoint Server 2013, may I ask why you want to use title rather than ID? ID being the stronger choice?

Comment: I want to create a link from another system to SharePoint and there I have only the title of the element i want to jump in.

Comment: How are you obtaining the title element? CSOM/JSOM? I did a little work similar recently, I'm wondering if you might be able to grab the ID and circumvent the issue

Comment: The title element is an generated Number from that application, which is imported in the SharePoint list using SQL

Comment: So has the item been created, or are you trying to create an item with the generated title? If the latter, that may explain why you cannot open the item, it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: The items are already created in that list and if I open a specific element manually from inside the normal list view I get all informations. But when going there through a direct link with using the title I get an empty mask. If I use the ID of this element I get the informations...

Comment: Again, so why not use the ID?

Comment: because i don't want to enter 400 individual links and the SharePoint created ID is not directly connected with "id" I've got in the other systen